# Python os.walk() does not work with tilde ~ in path

Tags: python, linux, operating-system, os.walk, tilde

I am trying to count files in a directory and subdirectories and it will be used for many users which I dont know before hand so I want to use "~" tilde in the path. But when I do the following python returns nothing:

```
import os 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("~/direcotry/sub_directory", topdown=True):
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))

    total += len(files)

print(f"Total number of files in directory is:{total}")
```

Comment: Try `os.path.expanduser("~")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the reply above the code works like this now:

```
import os 

exapnded_dir = os.path.expanduser('~/direcotry/sub_directory')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(exapnded_dir, topdown=True):
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))

    total += len(files)

print(f"Total number of files in directory is:{total}")
```